# Find all possible to ways to reach a point $N$ meters away using steps that are of lengths 1 meter or 2 meters.

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

> Find all possible to ways to reach a point $N$ meters away in only 2 possible steps that are of 1 meter and 2 meter respectively.

Now let me illustrate using an example: Let the point be 4 meters away. So all possible ways to reach the point:

1. (1,1,1,1)
2. (2,2)
3. (1,2,1)
4. (2,1,1)
5. (1,1,2)

My approach:

I sought to the computational power of my laptop, I brute forced to reach the solution.

Yet this isn't really a solution, I am looking for some more logically derived solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps find a recurrence?

Comment: What is that could you elaborate ?

Comment: Look up [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Comment: @Jens Thanks man, it looks like it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of ways of reaching a point $n$ meters away by taking steps of $1~\text{m}$ or $2~\text{m}$.  There is only one way to move $1~\text{m}$ (take a $1~\text{m}$ step), and two ways to move $2~\text{m}$ (take two $1~\text{m}$ steps or one $2~\text{m}$ step).  Hence, we have the initial conditions
\begin{align*}
a_1 & = 1\\
a_2 & = 2
\end{align*}
An admissible sequence of steps that results in moving $n$ meters must begin with a $1~\text{m}$ step or a $2~\text{m}$ step.  If it begins with a $1~\text{m}$ step, then it must be followed by an admissible sequence of steps that results in moving $(n - 1)~\text{m}$, of which there are $a_{n - 1}$.  If it begins with a $2~\text{m}$ step, then it must be followed by an admissible sequence of steps that results in moving $(n - 2)~\text{m}$, of which there are $a_{n - 2}$.  Hence, we have the recurrence relation
$$a_n = a_{n - 1} + a_{n - 2}$$
The first few terms of the sequence are $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55$, so this is the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Answer (score 0):

In *Mathematica* this function is called `IntegerPartitions`:

So:

```
IntegerPartitions[5, 4, {1, 2}]
```

means:  give all partitions of the number $N=5$ consisting of up to 4 "steps" (in your terms) of size $1$ and $2$ without respect to order.  The output is:

(*

{{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}}

*)

It is then a simple matter to get the three distinguishable orders of the first set of "paths" and the four distinguishable orders of the second set of "paths."

Comment: I am looking for a pen paper solution ,hope u can direct me.